# Can you use jokers to change which noble visits at the end of turn?

Tags: splendor

A player cannot refuse a visit from a noble.

But can you choose to use jokers to change which noble visits if you don’t have the gem colors required at end of turn?

Comment: Nobles aren't bought, with jokers or anything else. You gain one if you have the right cards in play. (Since they're free, there's on reason to refuse one.)

Comment: You can have multiple nobles, but you can only gain one per turn.

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot.

From the rules:

> At the end of their turn, a player automatically receives the visit from a noble if that player has the amount of bonuses (**and only bonuses**) required.

(emphasis mine)

A visit from a noble is determined only by the bonuses printed on the development cards.  Tokens, including the Joker token, cannot be used to get a visit from a noble.

Answer (score 2):

Nobles visit base on mines, not gems. You need mines that produce gems that match what is listed on the noble card. What gems you have is irrelevant.